# Problem with socket code C++ when send and hex message

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, hex

I try to send hex data to another device. The compilation does not lead to errors. But when I launch the function from the terminal nothing happens but a light should turn on. I put a cout on connect () to see if I have some connection problems but it answers 0 (so I have no problems) maybe it's how I write the hex code?
Besides the code I also insert the command line that I execute with the Hex code. The strange thing is that if I use any program like PacketSender with the same parameters it works.

> ./main 192.168.2.170 26810000A7

in attachment I also add the screenshot made on PacketSender.In addition what I can say is that if I leave the recv () command in the code once I give the command from the terminal the prompt remains pending ... if instead I comment the recv () once I give the command from the prompt it returns to the prompt but without doing anything (so without turning on the light). Does anyone have any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbfqR.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

// per compilare gcc connect_PE.cpp -lstdc++ -o main
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    std::string serveraddr = argv[1];

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serveraddr.c_str());
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(9761);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    cout << connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    const std::string hex = argv[2];

    char *number = strcpy(new char[hex.length() + 1], hex.c_str());


    send(sockfd, &number, 8, 0);
    recv(sockfd, &number, 8, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re passing the *address* of `number` when you should be passing its *value*.

Or even better, just pass `hex.data()` or `&hex[0]` – there’s no point in copying it.

Also note that you are sending a string of characters, not numbers in hexadecimal form.
(The first `char` is not `0x26` - that is, 38 - but `’2’`, wich is probably 50.)

If you want to send the corresponding numbers, you need to convert the input first.

Comment: you have some examples of how to implement the hex conversion of the input in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Sockets work very poorly with everything that is not char*, so it is better to immediately send a string from the terminal argument, and perform all the necessary transformations on the server.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).